# Is it possible to manually update the the unicode character database used by Python's unicodedata?

Tags: python, unicode

According to [this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unicodedata.html), unicodedata in Python 3.7 uses version 11 of the Unicode character database whereas the current version [appears to be 13](https://www.unicode.org/Public/13.0.0/)

Comment: I think the _official_ answer is to wait for the next version of Python. However, are you experiencing problems with the current version? If you mention what specific issue you have, maybe someone can help.

Comment: Just to minimize potential for unrecognized characters, seems strange to have this data coupled with the Python version - Python3.6 which is still current in many places  is based on version 9 and are users of python 2.7 doomed to stay with 5.2.0 ?

Comment: It looks like the data is compiled in at the c level - [this commit](https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/3aca40d3cb4b9b6741cf3073d71fbfc682cab96d) shows what gets changed when the version is updated.

Comment: python 2.7 is dead. Why to update a database for python 2?  In any case stability is the rule, so the package `tz` is keep split from python: timezone should change quicker and independently of python. If you really need to be updated, you must create a parser from Unicode database (and so, not using any database in any package). BTW there are not so important changes between 11 and 13, and the pdf file takes also several months to be published, so do not use undocumented version of unicode.